# StringBuilder.AppendFormat with an embedded tab in the format

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have spent the last 2 hours googling, either I am loosing touch with keywords, or I am the only one having this problem.

I need a tab delimited file

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Transaction line in lines)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\r\n", 
                                    line.portfolio_id, line.cp_client_id, line.instrument_id, line.sign_id, line.currency_id);

        }

        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(filefullpath,true))
        {                
            w.Write(sb.ToString());
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
        }
```

the above code, yields

```
PROD.3264-PAYMENTS;CUST.406;CASH-PAYMENT-DI;Pay;USD;
```

I am not sure where the semi-colons are coming from.

please can someone outthere shed some light...

thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like it should work to me.  If you run it in debugger do your variables all have the proper values?  They may have all been stuffed into `line.portfolio_id`

Comment: The semi colons are either in the data or caused by the viewer. I just ran a version of your code using string literals and it worked fine.

Comment: How did you get PROD.3264-PAYMENTS;CUST.406;CASH-PAYMENT-DI;Pay;USD;
result? What tool do you use to open file?

Comment: thanks mate - i have debugged, and i found "line" itself is good, properties are all individually assigned. even if all have been stuffed in, i shouldnt see the "Last semicolon"

Comment: Then something else is wrong.  I too ran your code with a mocked up Transaction list and got the expected result.

Comment: @petro - I have a datastructure, of type Transaction with all string properties. I have used VS2010. but the vendor has complained the same...

Comment: @Tim, if the semi colons are in the data, then atleast the "tab" should appear after the semicolon - correct?

Comment: Put a breakpoint just before the using statement and chek the value of your StringBuilder. While looking at it check also the name of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an extension in one of the libraries that i have referenced (and clearl misplaced). Someone must have written to avoid sending tab delimited files out. the fact that the lines in my code, stringbuilder contents are all good, until the ToString() method is called, meant that it is almost impossible to debug this.

```
public static string ToString(this StringBuilder sb)
    {
        return sb.ToString().Replace("\t", ";");            
    }
```

I am begining to have new respect for the documentation

So watch out for extensions (I am attached to extensions, but when you face issues like this, it makes it a bit difficult - well only for an hour)